# How to calculate/display number as "Top 5", "Top 10", "Top 15" and so on?

Tags: php, math

How would you create a function (in PHP) to return a value for the appropriate rounded ranking group (e.g. "Top 5", "Top 10", "Top 15", ... "Top 1 million", "Top 5 million", "Top 10 million", "Top 15 million").

Note that it should round up to the nearest 1, 5 or 10 - e.g. "Top 15 million" rather than "Top 12 million".

Example:

**Rank = Output**

- 1-5 = 5 (Top 5 ranking)
- 6-10 = 10 (Top 10 ranking)
- 11-15 = 15 (Top 15 ranking)

This should work all the way up to trillions.

My current function works (sort of) however it would return a value for a ranking group of top 15 as top 20 instead.

```
   private function format_number_iollions($amount,$style=null) {
        $amount = (0 + str_replace(',', '', $amount));   
        if (!is_numeric($amount)){
            return false;
        }

        $plusString = '';
        switch ($style){
            case 'plus':
                $plusString = '+';
            break;
        }

        if ($style==='rank' && $amount<=10){
            return 10;
        }

        // filter and format it 
        if ($amount>1000000000000){

            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/1000000000000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/1000000000000));
            }

            $v .= $plusString.' trillion';
        } else if ($amount>1000000000){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/1000000000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/1000000000));
            }

            $v .= $plusString.' billion';
        } else if ($amount>1000000){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/1000000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/1000000));
            }

            $v .= $plusString.' million';
        } else if ($amount>100000){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/100000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/100000));
            }

            $v .= '00,000'.$plusString;
        } else if ($amount>10000){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/10000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/10000));
            }

            $v .= '0,000'.$plusString;
        } else if ($amount>1000){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/1000));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/1000));
            }

            $v .= ',000'.$plusString;
        } else if ($amount>100){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/100));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/100));
            }

            $v .= '00'.$plusString;
        } else if ($amount>10){ 
            if ($style==='rank'){
                $v = ceil(($amount/10));
            } else {
                $v = floor(($amount/10));
            }

            $v .= '0'.$plusString;
        } else {
            return number_format($amount);
        }

        return $v;
    }
```

**UPDATE** - the final solution is this function (if anyone needs it):

```
private function get_rank_group($rawrank) {
    // Divide by 1000 and count how many divisions were done
    $rank_scale = 0;
    while ($rawrank >= 1000) {
        $rawrank /= 1000;
        $rank_scale++;
    }
    // Determine which Top X can be
    if ($rawrank >= 100) {
        $lim_name = (floor(($rawrank-1) / 50) + 1) * 50;
    } else {
        $lim_name = (floor(($rawrank-1) / 5) + 1) * 5;
    }
    // if its in the next higher level
    if ($lim_name >= 1000) {
        $lim_name = '1';
        $rank_scale++; 
    }
    static $rank_scale_names = array('', ',000', ' Million', ' Billion', ' Trillion',  ' Quadrillion', ' Quintillion', ' Sextillion', ' Septillion');
    if (!isset($rank_scale_names[$rank_scale])){
        return null; //too much - add higher word-numbers to $rank_scale_names
    } else {
        return "$lim_name{$rank_scale_names[$rank_scale]}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use PHP's `%` operator.

Comment: at least I'm not sure I understand exactly what should be the output. Could you please provide several examples with `$amount` inputs and desired outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  function get_rank_group($rawrank) {
     // Divide by 1000 and count how many divisions were done
     $rank_scale = 0;
     while ($rawrank >= 1000) {
       $rawrank /= 1000;
       $rank_scale++;
     }
     // Determine which Top X can be
     static $rank_split = array(3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 500); 
     $lim_name = false;
     // Look for a group, which is not less than the number
     foreach ($rank_split as $lim) { 
       if ($rawrank <= $lim) {
         $lim_name = $lim;
         break;
       }
     }
     // If nothing was found then it is a Top 1 of (next scaler) eg. 501 is Top 1 Thousand
     if ($lim_name === false) {
       $lim_name = '1';
       $rank_scale++;
     }
     static $rank_scale_names = array('', ' Thousand', ' Million', ' Billion', ' Trillion',  ' Quadrillion', ' Quintillion', ' Sextillion', ' Septillion'); // etc
     if (!isset($rank_scale_names[$rank_scale])) return 'too much!'; // just check
     return "Top $lim_name{$rank_scale_names[$rank_scale]}";
  }

  // Tests
  $tests = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 49, 50, 51, 299, 300, 301, 12345, 654321, 234567890, 1234567890123456789);
  foreach ($tests as $test) {
    print ("$test -> " . get_rank_group($test) . PHP_EOL);
  }
```

The output:

```
1 -> Top 3
2 -> Top 3
3 -> Top 3
4 -> Top 5
16 -> Top 20
49 -> Top 50
50 -> Top 50
51 -> Top 100
299 -> Top 300
300 -> Top 300
301 -> Top 500
12345 -> Top 15 Thousand
654321 -> Top 1 Million
234567890 -> Top 300 Million
1234567890123456789 -> Top 3 Quintillion
```

Comment: Thank you - a great solution. I am using this in combination with Turo's adjustment below!

Answer (score 1):

As an improvement of AterLux's Solution

```
...
// Determine which Top X can be
if ($rawrank >= 100) {
    $lim_name = (floor(($rawrank-1) / 50) + 1) * 50;
} else {
    $lim_name = (floor(($rawrank-1) / 5) + 1) * 5;
}
// if its in the next higher level
if ($lim_name >= 1000) {
    $lim_name = '1';
    $rank_scale++; 
}
static $rank_scale_names = array( ...
```

Output

```
1 -> Top 5
5 -> Top 5
9 -> Top 10
10 -> Top 10
12 -> Top 15
16 -> Top 20
49 -> Top 50
50 -> Top 50
51 -> Top 55
299 -> Top 300
300 -> Top 300
301 -> Top 350
995 -> Top 1 Thousand
12345 -> Top 15 Thousand
654321 -> Top 700 Thousand
234567890 -> Top 250 Million
1234567890123456789 -> Top 5 Quintillion
```